# Adobe Illustrator: Unable to edit text of design that was made in newer version?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to edit the text of a design that was made with a newer version of AI.

However, when I try to select the text, it shows up as an artboard.

[image]

How would I edit this text? Do I just have to delete all of the characters individually and insert a new textbox?

Comment: The text you selected is not an artboard. It's a separate object. It looks like the text has been converted to outlines. To edit it you'll need to delete it and retype it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, it appears as though Ai *outlined the type* or the type was outlined in the original file and is **not** live, editable text. You will indeed need to recreate the text if you wish to edit what it reads.

---

Illustrator files are, by default, **not** "backwards compatible". In fact, there's a warning pop up when you open a newer version file in legacy versions telling you this exactly.

[image]

Note the *"Some data loss may occur."* sentence.

Illustrator tries it's best to use as much of the newer data as it can. However, because newer versions have new features and possibly a new code base around existing features, the files should **never** be assumed to be intact if you see the "newer version warning" when opening the file in a legacy version.

To avoid this you can use the version of AI the file was created in. Or, save the AI file in a more backwards compatible format, such as PDF or EPS. You can also directly save AI files to legacy versions in the *second* save as dialog which appears when saving a file.

[image]